# urllib.parse vs urlparse: How do I get python 2.7 to recognize urllib?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've seen some topics related to this same issue, but have been unable to find a solution that fits my situation. While trying to run a python library, I received the error `ImportError: No module named urllib.parse`, which I understand is because I'm running Python 2.7 and not Python 3. I do have urllib3 in my python folder, it seems like it's just unable to access it because of the name difference. I am not able to change this in the source code, nor do I want to switch to Python 3. Is there any other way to solve this problem and get Python 2.7 to recognize urllib3?

Comment: There are some major differences between urllib2 and urllib3. See if you can change the import statement to `import urllib2 as urllib` and get it running? This may or may not work depending on what you're doing.

Comment: The python2  equivalent of `urllib.parse` is the [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) module in the standard library.  `urllib3` is a third party library, it isn't part of the standard library.  I think your choices are either to find a python2 version of the library that you are trying to use, or switch to python3.

Comment: Use: `from urlparse import urlparse`

Comment: Python2 & 3 differences and how to make compatible code for both here: http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#urllib-module If you can't edit that source then it's as snakecharmerb says.

Comment: @t.m.adam doesn't work in python3.6.0

Comment: @BorisBurkov Yes, for Python3 use `from urllib.parse import urlparse`

Answer (score 2):

Version-compatible solution (tested on 2.7.10 and 3.6.0):

```
import six

if six.PY2:
    from urlparse import urlparse
elif six.PY3:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
```